# What should I do in order to display how many loops it takes to get a favourable number?

Tags: c#

Im new to programming and Im currently attempting to make a dice program, where the user can input how many throws they would like to do and then a list will display how many throws it took to get a specific number, in this case that number is 6 (later on I'd like to make it for all numbers 1-6) How should I go about doing this?

Im currently trying to use an if-statement to recognize when a specific number is rolled, currently I want the program to recognize the number 6, but im a bit unsure how to display the amount of rolls it took to get that number, in a list, and also keeping the loop going until all rolls have been executed.

```cs
private void Btnkast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool throws;
    int numberofthrows = 0;

    int dice;
    Random dicethrow = new Random();
    throws = int.TryParse(rtbantal.Text, out numberofthrows);
    int[] list = new int[numberofthrows];

    for (int i = 0; i <= numberofthrows; i++)
    {
        dice = dicethrow.Next(1, 7);
        if (dice == 6)
        {...}
    }
}
```

Also, the only reason I use tryparse is to prevent crashes when having to handle with string-values.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(i);`?

Comment: You already have the number of throws it took; that's `i + 1`, right?

Comment: I currently use a windows forms app on visual studio. I tried setting the text in a textbox to the value of I, but that results in the text getting overwritten every time the program rolls a new 6

Comment: ``` i ```  is supposed to be the variable that keeps the loop going, numberofthrows is user-decided and the program will loop that many times. My intentions is to have the program recognize every time the dice has the value 6, and then store the amount of throws it took since the last 6 was rolled, in a list.

Comment: Suggest you don't name a variable `list` and then store an array in it. You want `i < numberofthrows` if you expect to do around the user entered number of times, otherwise you are trying one extra (`0` case). Inside your `if` `i+1` is how many times you tried to get to a 6.

Answer (score 0):

I have written this for you using a C# Console Application, but I'm sure you will be able to edit it to fit your requirements for Windows Forms.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random(); // create Random object

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between  1 and 6: "); // prompt user to enter a number between 1 and 6
        int chosenNumberInt;
        var chosenNumber = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out chosenNumberInt); // check to see if user actually entered a number.  If so, put that number into the chosenNumberInt variable


        Console.WriteLine("How many rolls would you like?"); // prompt user to enter how many rolls they would like to have
        int chosenRollsInt;
        var chosenRolls = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out chosenRollsInt);

        Console.WriteLine(); // to create space
        Console.WriteLine(); // to create space

        Console.WriteLine("Chosen Number = " + chosenNumberInt + " --- Chosen Rolls = " + chosenRollsInt); // show user what they entered
        Console.WriteLine("------------");

        int count = 0;
        int numberRolled = 0;
        var lstRolls = new List<int>(); // create list object

        for(int i = 1; i <= chosenRollsInt; i++)
        {
            count++;
            int dice = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            numberRolled = dice;

            lstRolls.Add(numberRolled); // add each roll to the list

            Console.WriteLine("Roll " + i + " = " + numberRolled); // show each roll
        }

        var attempts = lstRolls.Count; // how many rolls did you do
        var firstIndexOfChosenNumber = lstRolls.FindIndex(x => x == chosenNumberInt) + 1; // have to add 1 because finding the index is 0-based
        Console.WriteLine("-------------");

        if(firstIndexOfChosenNumber == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("The chosen number was " + chosenNumberInt + " and that number was NEVER rolled with " + chosenRollsInt + " rolls.");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("The chosen number was " + chosenNumberInt + " and the number of rolls it took to hit that number was " + firstIndexOfChosenNumber);
    }
}
```

Something that I didn't add would be the validation to ensure that the user does indeed enter a number between 1 and 6, but you can do that I'm sure.

I have created a [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JIOkW6) that proves this code does work and even shows you each roll.

Let me know if this helps or if you need any more assistance.

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment on my original post, I have edited my code to allow the user to enter the number they want, along with how many rolls.  Then, once all of the rolls have been completed, I find the index of the first occurrence of the number they selected in the beginning.

Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: Yes, this is definently going to help me a bunch, thank you! I just have one quick question, just out of interest, how would I go about making an array/list and also making it so that the user can choose how many throws, and then displaying the data that your code displays, but in a list. For example, if the user chooses the number 4, and the amount of rolls to 100, the list would show 16 to 17 numbers in a list, and those numbers would be the amount of rolls it took to get 4. I feel like im asking too much but idk :D

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm misunderstanding your question.  I get when the user chooses the number 4, and wants 100 rolls.. but what is 16-17 numbers in a list?

Comment: Updated my code, along with a little update explanation.

Comment: What I meant by 16-17 numbers in a list is that the list will show a certain amount of numbers, specificly the amount of times the dice rolled the chosen number. The numbers themselves stand for how many rolls it took to achieve the chosen number. A dice has 6 numbers, and with 100 rolls you should expect around 17 4's on average, thats why I wrote 16-17 numbers. Hope that clarifies what I meant, though I must point out that your code has helped me immensely, the only  thing left now I believe is to adapt that code to windows forms, which shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Okay, so in order to count how many times the chosen number was rolled, you would simply need to add a new variable and set it to count how many times the chosen number was rolled in the list variable that I created `lstRolls`.  So, something like this: `var amountOfChosenNumber = lstRolls.Where(x => x == chosenNumberInt).Count();`.  Let me know if this helps

Comment: @Outliggare if this answer helped you, please mark it as accepted so that this question can be seen as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Read the comments I added in the code

```
private void Btnkast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool throws;
    int numberofthrows = 0;

    int dice;
    Random dicethrow = new Random();
    throws = int.TryParse(rtbantal.Text, out numberofthrows);
    List<int> list = new List<int>(); //I changed this to a list

    for (int i = 0; i < numberofthrows; i++)
    {

        dice = dicethrow.Next(1, 7);
        list.Add(dice); //add every roll to the array to check later the values if you want
        if (dice == 6)
        {
           //Print that you found 6 at the roll number list.Count
           Console.WriteLine("Found 6 at roll number: " + list.Count);
           break; //probably break the loop so you won't continue doing useless computation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Two things I am seeing.. in C# list objects use the `Count` property.. not `Length`... secondly, with your `for` loop, that would iterate 1 extra time past what the user wanted... you need to change the `<=` to `<` if you're starting at `0` for your iterator.